# Finding the Joint Density from the Conditional Hazard Functions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X_{1}<X_{2}<\dots<X_{n}$ be continuous nonnegative random variables where the hazard functions are  $$\lambda_1(t)=\lambda*e^{\beta*g(t)}$$ 
$$\lambda_i(t|x_{i-1})=\lambda*e^{\beta*g(t)}*I(t\geq x_{i-1})$$ for $i=2,\dots,n$. I have to find the joint density of $X_{1},X_{2},\dots,X_{n}$ and a sufficient statistic for $(\lambda,\beta)$. 
First I found the individuals densities by the using the standard formula obtaining 
$$ 
f(x_1)= \lambda*e^{\beta*g(x_1)}*e^{-\int_0^{x_1}\lambda*e^{\beta*g(t)}dt}$$
$$ f(x_i|x_{i-1})= \lambda*e^{\beta*g(x_i)}*e^{-\int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i}\lambda*e^{\beta*g(t)}dt}$$
for $i=2,\dots,n$. Then too find the join density i multiplied it all together obtaining

$$f(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\lambda^{n}*e^{\beta*\sum_{i=1}^{n}g(x_i)}*e^{-\int_{0}^{x_n}\lambda*e^{\beta*g(t)}dt}$$ 
for $x_1<\dots<x_n$. However this seems wrong because I do not think you can factor out the parameters from the integral. So what did i do wrong?